# Ckeditor issue with malformed html

Tags: javascript, html, ckeditor, fckeditor

I'm having a huge issue with a customer. I provided him a CMS that allows you to send mails, can edit them from the ckeditor. Last week, he edited one of them, and left some malformed html there... it was something like:

```
<a href="mylink.html" _blank">
```

That small piece of malformed html caused ckeditor to crash the entire page next time he tried to access the edit mail page. Ckeditor is not replacing the textarea also, sounds reasonable.

I'm not getting any error on the script, anywhere in chrome. Just Firefox tells me that the script timed out.

Will appreciate any help, due that I'm stuck with this issue.

Thanks so much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Try this if you can modify the html

```
<a href="mylink.html" target="_blank">Som Text/image</a>
```

Comment: Thanks! but that will not fix my issue. I want to know how to prevent the issue of occuring again, or at least how to handle it.

Comment: the best thing to do is to advise him about errors. Or remove the button of code in ckeditor. I think you can activate or deactivate buttons [link]http://docs.cksource.com/CKEditor_3.x/Developers_Guide